# Hadoop 2.6.0 - Asking password for the user while running the start up script?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I've installed hadoop 2.6.0 in ubuntu linux on a pseudo distributed mode. Everything is fine except this issue. When I run the start-dfs.sh script to start daemons it's asking for the linux user password. Not sure why? It's asking for the password for every daemon (namenode, datanode & sec namenode). Could you please help to address this issue?

```
huser@ubuntu:~/hadoop$ sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
huser@localhost's password:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's the password of your huser, the user you are logged to!

Comment: I don't want to key in the password. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you did not setup `passwordless ssh` for huser@localhost. getenfor

If you did setup `passwordless ssh` make sure `selinux` is disabled by using `$sestatus` command.

Note: You should run `sestatus` as a `sudo` user.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you can use the following one time set up steps to eliminate the need to enter password when running hadoop commands, for example, start-dfs.sh, start-yarn.sh:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id user@localhost
```

replace user with your username. It was tested on Ubuntu 16.04.2, hadoop-2.7.3, jdk1.8.0_121

**Note**: 1. when execute "ssh-keygen -t rsa" command, you can simply press ENTER three times to accept the default values. 2. when execute "ssh-copy-id user@localhost" command, "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" enter "yes", then your password

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574837/why-hadoop-asks-for-password-before-starting-any-of-the-services/43007877#43007877) also